# Sho, greek letter

Tags: characters, greek

I wanted to print the greek letter sho (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sho_(letter)), but I have noticed that it is not in the default package. Does anyone know if there is a package for this letter?

Some examples from Wikipedia

[image: examples from Wikipedia]

Comment: As a workaround you could use [thorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)): `\th` or `\TH` with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (or `\textthorn` from the `tipa` package)

Comment: By the way, whenever you  are searching for a symbol, [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround you could use the very similar letter [Thorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)), which is available with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` as `\th` (minuscule) and `TH` (majuscule).

Alternatively, you can search through [`symbolsa4.pdf`](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) for `thorn`, there are quite a other packages that provide one or more variants. Maybe you prefer one of those.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\let\sho\th
\let\Sho\TH

\begin{document}

This is a minuscule: \sho

This is a majuscule: \Sho

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Answer (score 3):

Homegrown alternatives

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\textsf{\stackengine{0pt}{p}{b}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}

\stackengine{1ex}{b}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{b}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want a thorn and you are using luatex or xetex, the character is available as U+03F8 (ϸ) in many fonts, I get

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}

this is a sho: ϸ
\end{document}
```